# How to handle different versions of format in reading data?

Tags: c++, version

With the update of software, the format of the input data may change from version 1 to 2, 3 and so on. The software want to be back-compatible. How to handle those different versions when coding?

For example, I have a class `Data`, which has some member variables. `Read` data from file is to specify those member variables. In a new version, the class `Data` has more member variables. To make back-compatible, the new member variables have default values when reading old version data. How to implement it?

Comment: Some example of what you are talking about perhaps

Comment: Consider using strategy pattren if you need to support run-time switching versions.

Answer (score 2):

Add an entry to the *header*(1) of the data file that indicates which version it is. When you access the file check the version information in the header and use the appropriate set of functions to load the data.

If the data file doesn't already have some type of header you should add one.

```
struct header
{
    char   signature_[16]; // some arbitrary data identifying it as your data file
    int    version_;       // version number
    // ... more data ...
};

header_ hdr;
ReadHeader(inFile, &hdr);

Data* data;
switch(hdr)
{
case 1: data = LoadVersion1Data(inFile); break;
case 2: data = LoadVersion2Data(inFile); break;
case 3: data = LoadVersion3Data(inFile); break;
}
```

---

<sub>1. A header is simple a block of data that typically has a known fixed size and resides at the beginning of the data file.</sub>